# Change week days based on the locale in swings

Tags: java, swing

I am working on an application(Swing application) which can run in both english and german languages.
There is a date picker requirement, for that they have used JDatePickerImpl from (source forge.net)

Now the requirement is,

if the application runs in english Week starting day is Sunday..... Saturday

if the application runs in german Week starting day is Monday..... Sunday

But the JDatePickerImpl  showing Sunday, Monday,........ Saturday

How to change the week starting day based on locale...

### Here is my  code snippet....

```
   private JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter format = 
   new  JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter(){


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {


    Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
    if (cal == null) {
    return "";
    }

    return DateUtil.dateToString(
        PlasaApplication.getTranslator().getCurrentLanguage()
            .equals("de") ? DateUtil.germanDateFormat
            : DateUtil.usDateFormat, cal.getTime());

}

@Override
public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {


    return DateUtil.getDateFromString(text,
        PlasaApplication.getTranslator().getCurrentLanguage()
            .equals("de") ? DateUtil.germanDateFormat
            : DateUtil.usDateFormat);

}
};
private JDatePickerImpl fromDatePicker = (JDatePickerImpl) JDateComponentFactory
    .createJDatePicker(format);


private JDatePickerImpl toDatePicker = (JDatePickerImpl) JDateComponentFactory
    .createJDatePicker(format);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the API for JDatePickerImpl and see if it has a way to set the week start day. If it does call that method in the same way you are setting the date format for each locale value.

If it doesn't then there is nothing you can do using that particular date picker. You will need to either make your own variant of it or use a different date picker.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your code and set the Locale according to your requirements. By default, the System Locale is being picked up.

```
datePicker.setLocale(new Locale("es", "ES"));
datePicker.setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL);
```

For more [info](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.jdatepicker/jdatepicker/1.3.0/net/sourceforge/jdatepicker/impl/JDatePickerImpl.java).

Comment: How are you trying to set the Locale? Are you getting any error?

Comment: toDatePicker.setLocale(new Locale("de", "DE"));
this is the way I am setting,, no error, but Date picker is showing same as earlier